# Angular 2+ [onClick] vs (click)

Tags: angular

What is the difference between binding a click handler `[onClick]="func"` and `(click)="func()"`, besides the fact that one uses `@Input` and the other uses `@Output`? Is there practical advantage/disadvantage or idiomatic preference for either?

Answer (score 0):

they are both events,  use onclick when assign its handler inline, and the other click when assign using an event listener (recommended).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers